# Error Asserting two decimals

Tags: c#, decimal, assert

Can anyone help me understand, because the expected value and the actual value have different results in the `ToString()` method. When I open the watch for me it is the same value.

Thanks

**Code:**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SerializeDecimalWithTwoDecimals()
    {
        var expected = decimal.Round(1.00M,2);
        var actual = decimal.Round(1M,2);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected.ToString(), actual.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Have you looked at what expected.ToString() and actual.ToString() represent?  While decimals are guaranteed accuracy for floating point numbers, that doesn't guarantee they won't chop trailing zeros as they do not affect the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft C# documentation:

> The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeros in a Decimal number. Trailing zeros do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. However, trailing zeros might be revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Don't believe the Watch window, basically. It can play silly games with string representations of values. The two values are equal (`expected == actual` will be true), but they're not identical - the trailing zeroes are preserved.

Here, the `Round` method isn't actually changing the values at all, so you've effectively got:

```
var expected = 1.00m;
var actual = 1m;

Assert.AreEqual(expected.ToString(), actual.ToString());
```

... and `1.00m.ToString()` is "1.00", whereas `1m.ToString()` is "1".